# functional component doesn't re-render on props change

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, whenever I get new props from the parent, the new props are logged correctly on the console, but the rendered HTML is never updated after the initial render:

```
export default function(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(props)
  
  // initially, props.something is defined
  // every time props changes (from the parent) props.something is redefined as expected and logged here
  console.log(props.something)
  
  // initially, props.something is rendered correctly
  // every time props.something changes (from the parent) the HTML never updates
  return (
    {state.something && <div>{state.something}</div>}
  )
}
```

I already tried using `useEffect()` even though I don't see the point, but it it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 9):

State will not update just because props change, this is why you need `useEffect`.

```
export default function(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(props)

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(props.something)
  }, [props.something])
  
  // initially, props.something is defined
  // every time props changes (from the parent) props.something is redefined as expected and logged here
  console.log(props.something)
  
  // initially, props.something is rendered correctly
  // every time props.something changes (from the parent) the HTML never updates
  return (<div>{state.something}</div>)
}
```

adding `props.something` to the array as the second argument to `useEffect` tells it to watch for changes to `props.something` and run the effect when a change was detected.

Update: In this specific example, there is no reason to copy props to state, just use the prop directly.

Comment: I thought that since the whole function (component) is called every time, then the state is also reset every time.

Comment: If the state was reset every time the function rendered, then you wouldn't need state, you could just use a local variable (or props.something) directly. The whole point of state is that the functional component can preserve state between renders.

Comment: That is true. I'm trying to wrap my head around React coming from Ember. Thanks for the clarification, it makes sense.

Comment: +1 but: Is it just me, or does it feel much cleaner instead providing data via a `Context` provider (e.g. `useContext` hook) so that you can avoid copying props to state?

Comment: Context seems like overkill for this one thing. But, in this specific example, there is no reason to copy props to state, just use the prop directly. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you copy props to state only once, when initial values set.

It's almost never a good idea to copy props to component state though. You can read about it [react docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state)